# Use Mac's Preview to display PDF files from TexShop?

Tags: pdf, viewers, texshop, mac

I am sure there is a simple way to do this but my internet search yielded nothing ..

I prefer using Mac's `Preview` to display PDF files rather than `TexShop's` internal PDF viewer. `TexMaker` has an option to use an external viewer, but I couldn't find a similar option in `TexShop`.

Is there a way I can accomplish this ?

Comment: Interesting.. Any reason why you prefer Preview? I found that TeXShops's viewer is actually better than Mac Preview, mainly due to the reasons I pointed out in [How to create internet link in PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107832/how-to-create-internet-link-in-pdf).  Plus if you are using synctex, then you can right click in the PDF and have the corresponding file open automatically to the correct spot -- this is extremely useful. Not sure if that will work with Preview or not.

Comment: No, this is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: @AlanMunn: [This](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/TeXShop-Engine-to-use-Acrobat-as-previewer-td5087826.html) seems to provide `engine` script to do so, but I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for TeXshop.

Comment: @PeterGrill - I am trying to do this because fonts in builtin viewer are fuzzy, but displays fine in Preview

Comment: @JosephWright - this it not a feature request because it is possible through configuration, as Peter Grill's link shows

Comment: I agree — it wasn't a feature request; it was a request to know if something was technically possible, which is a very different thing.